# Is it possible to disable the swipe gesture and only make the pan gesture work in a scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I use a `UIScrollView` to show some images. I find both swipe gesture and pan gesture work. Is it possible to only make pan gesture work at a time?

**I tried this code:**

```
for gestureRecognizer in scrollView.gestureRecognizers ?? [] {
    if gestureRecognizer is UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. I print `scrollView.gestureRecognizers!`, get the gesture list:

> UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer
>
> UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer
>
> _UIDragAutoScrollGestureRecognizer
>
> UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer

I tried `UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer`:

```
if gestureRecognizer is UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
}
```

It says `Use of undeclared type 'UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer'`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank s for your comment.  I try to make the scrollView scroll  by only drag it not swipe over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly... maybe you could use the following `UIScrollViewDelegate` method:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
}
```

Comment: Thank you, André Slotta. Now I think it is unable  to  distinguish between drag and swipe in a scrollview.